# How to disable Vagrant port forwarding for SSH?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I would like to set up VirtualBox via Vagrant in a way that resembles my cloud provider setup as close as possible. This means:

- VM is reachable via some public IP (e.g. 192.168.0.2)
- A given public SSH key is set up in `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys`
- Bonus: The default user is root (but that's probably another question)

My Vagrantfile is:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/focal64"
  config.vm.define "master" do | w |
   w.vm.hostname = "master"
   w.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.2"
   w.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.0.0.2"
   w.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.memory = "4096"
  vb.cpus = 2
  vb.name = "master"
   end
  end
  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/bob.pub", destination: "~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
 
end
```

When Vagrant sets the box up it does some port forwarding for SSH for some reason:

```
==> master: Forwarding ports...
    master: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> master: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> master: Booting VM...
==> master: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    master: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    master: SSH username: vagrant
    master: SSH auth method: private key
```

So if you want to SSH into the box then you need:

```
ssh -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1
```

But I would like to be able to have the setup without the port forwarding on the regular port and public IP, i.e. `ssh vagrant@192.168.0.2`

Is this somehow possible? The network settings in VirtualBox seem to be alright, but `ssh vagrant@192.168.0.2` times out. Not sure how this port forwarding makes even sense.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: The sense of the port forwarding is that 127.0.0.1:22 is the ssh port *of your machine*, i.e. likely taken. Vagrant ensures that ports of your machine and ports of the box don't collide.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this.

Clearly define port and host for each VM via [config.ssh](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/ssh_settings)

> config.ssh.host = "ip"
>
> config.ssh.port = "port"